# Combining points and their values within the same cell in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, fields-attributes, point-in-polygon, summarizing

I have two shapafiles: points and vector grid. I need to combine points which are in the same cell(or cross cell) and sum their values. How can I do this in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

[Since QGIS 3.18](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/index.html#feature-support-for-min-max-majority-sum-mean-and-median-functions-on-numerical-arrays) using the [`array_sum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#array-sum) function, you can use the following expression on the grid layer to calculate the sum of the `value` attribute from all points that are within a grid-cell automatically:

```
array_sum (overlay_contains ('points', value))
```

*Screenshot: the expression (together with `to_int` to get integer values) calculates the blue value for each grid cell: sum of the values of all red points within this cell:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a spatial join using the join attributes by location tool. You can choose to sum the attribute field from the points layer. So this should output a new grid layer with the sum of the points attribute

See this tutorial for how to perform it

http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html